# How to use \foreach to simplify the code?

Tags: beamer, minted, foreach

I needed to create an animated code sample presentation, so I decided to use `beamer` + `minted`. That's what I could finally come up with:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand<>{\iterdemo}[3]{%
  \begin{onlyenv}#4
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \ifthenelse{#3 = 1}
        {\inputminted[highlightlines=#1,highlightcolor=structure!50!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo1.pas}}
        {\inputminted[highlightlines=#1,highlightcolor=structure!20!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo1.pas}}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{onlyenv}<4-44>
          \ifthenelse{#3 = 2}
          {\inputminted[highlightlines=#2,highlightcolor=structure!50!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo2.pas}}
          {\inputminted[highlightlines=#2,highlightcolor=structure!20!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo2.pas}}
        \end{onlyenv}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{onlyenv}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \iterdemo<1>{0}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<2>{5}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<3>{6}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<4>{6}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<5>{8}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<6>{8}{2}{2}
  \iterdemo<7>{8}{3}{2}
  \iterdemo<8>{8}{3}{1}

  \iterdemo<9>{9}{3}{1}
  \iterdemo<10>{10}{3}{1}
  \iterdemo<11>{10}{3}{2}
  \iterdemo<12>{10}{4}{2}
  \iterdemo<13>{10}{4}{1}

  \iterdemo<14>{11}{4}{1}
  \iterdemo<15>{12}{4}{1}
  \iterdemo<16>{12}{4}{2}
  \iterdemo<17>{12}{5}{2}
  \iterdemo<18>{12}{5}{1}

  \iterdemo<19>{13}{5}{1}
  \iterdemo<20>{14}{5}{1}
  \iterdemo<21>{14}{5}{2}
  \iterdemo<22>{14}{6}{2}
  \iterdemo<23>{14}{6}{1}

  \iterdemo<24>{15}{6}{1}
  \iterdemo<25>{16}{6}{1}
  \iterdemo<26>{16}{6}{2}
  \iterdemo<27>{16}{7}{2}
  \iterdemo<28>{16}{7}{1}

  \iterdemo<29>{17}{7}{1}
  \iterdemo<30>{18}{7}{1}
  \iterdemo<31>{18}{7}{2}
  \iterdemo<32>{18}{8}{2}
  \iterdemo<33>{18}{8}{1}

  \iterdemo<34>{19}{8}{1}
  \iterdemo<35>{20}{8}{1}
  \iterdemo<36>{20}{8}{2}
  \iterdemo<37>{20}{9}{2}
  \iterdemo<38>{20}{9}{1}

  \iterdemo<39>{21}{9}{1}
  \iterdemo<40>{22}{9}{1}
  \iterdemo<41>{22}{9}{2}
  \iterdemo<42>{22}{10}{2}
  \iterdemo<43>{22}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<44>{24}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<45>{24}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<46>{26}{0}{1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code is obviously suboptimal due to heavy duplication (and it was pain to create it!). However, the following approaches to fight the hand-work didn't play for me:

1. Using `<+->` overlay specification instead of hard-coded numbers doesn't have effect: the content appears on every page.
2. It seemed that `\foreach` loop would easily remove a lot of duplication in the central part of code, but I couldn't find a way to pass expanded value as a `minted` option *highlightlines*. This is probably due to `pgfkeys` nature of `minted` options.

Is it possible to simplify the above code, e.g. by using a loop?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please make your MWE compilable? We don't have `iterdemo1.pas` thus cannot test your code. What is the intended result of your code?

Comment: @samcarter: they're just arbitrary pascal files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you have in mind re 2, but this works...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand<>{\iterdemo}[3]{%
  \begin{onlyenv}#4
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \ifthenelse{#3 = 1}
        {\inputminted[highlightlines=#1,highlightcolor=structure!50!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo1.pas}}
        {\inputminted[highlightlines=#1,highlightcolor=structure!20!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo1.pas}}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{onlyenv}<4-44>
          \ifthenelse{#3 = 2}
          {\inputminted[highlightlines=#2,highlightcolor=structure!50!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo2.pas}}
          {\inputminted[highlightlines=#2,highlightcolor=structure!20!white]{Delphi}{iterdemo2.pas}}
        \end{onlyenv}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{onlyenv}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\foreach \x / \y / \z / \a in {1/0/0/1,2/5/0/1,3/6/0/1,4/6/0/1,5/8/0/1,6/8/2/2,7/8/3/2,8/8/3/1,9/9/3/1,10/10/3/1,11/10/3/2,12/10/4/2,13/10/4/1}
{

    \iterdemo<\x>{\y}{\z}{\a}
   }

  \iterdemo<14>{11}{4}{1}
  \iterdemo<15>{12}{4}{1}
  \iterdemo<16>{12}{4}{2}
  \iterdemo<17>{12}{5}{2}
  \iterdemo<18>{12}{5}{1}

  \iterdemo<19>{13}{5}{1}
  \iterdemo<20>{14}{5}{1}
  \iterdemo<21>{14}{5}{2}
  \iterdemo<22>{14}{6}{2}
  \iterdemo<23>{14}{6}{1}

  \iterdemo<24>{15}{6}{1}
  \iterdemo<25>{16}{6}{1}
  \iterdemo<26>{16}{6}{2}
  \iterdemo<27>{16}{7}{2}
  \iterdemo<28>{16}{7}{1}

  \iterdemo<29>{17}{7}{1}
  \iterdemo<30>{18}{7}{1}
  \iterdemo<31>{18}{7}{2}
  \iterdemo<32>{18}{8}{2}
  \iterdemo<33>{18}{8}{1}

  \iterdemo<34>{19}{8}{1}
  \iterdemo<35>{20}{8}{1}
  \iterdemo<36>{20}{8}{2}
  \iterdemo<37>{20}{9}{2}
  \iterdemo<38>{20}{9}{1}

  \iterdemo<39>{21}{9}{1}
  \iterdemo<40>{22}{9}{1}
  \iterdemo<41>{22}{9}{2}
  \iterdemo<42>{22}{10}{2}
  \iterdemo<43>{22}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<44>{24}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<45>{24}{0}{1}
  \iterdemo<46>{26}{0}{1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but doesn't remove the duplication :-( The slide numbers are still specified manually in spite of they are a just a natural numbers sequence. I would also expect that slide groups 2..6 (slides 9-38) could be united into one foreach body, as the \iterdemo arguments between these groups differ only by slide number offset.